# How to run a non-web-server long running Nodejs process in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I created a Nodejs program that is intended to be executed as a long-running process unattended. The program works on localhost when running `npm start`. I need to be able to '`tail -f`' its stdout on demand. There is no port it listens to. Does Google App Engine support this use case? If so, how to configure it?

I have deployed the app with following `app.yaml` file but it doesn't seem to work. At least the stdout of the instance is empty/unexpected. I believe the reason is App Engine is designed for web server and this process failed to pass health check of some sort.

```
runtime: nodejs
vm: true
```

btw, on Heroku this use case is clearly supported because it has two types of dyno: web and worker. Obviously worker dyno is the choice.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I believe I'm having the same issues. My instances work but appear to be constantly restarting every 15 minutes. I've attempted to disable health checking but it had no effect.

Comment: @AlanHaverty, no I haven't. Someone from Google suggests task queue. But I only found task queue docs in standard env, not in flexible env for  Nodejs. Besides, the task queue seems over-complicated for a simple use case like mine. I ended up with compute engine to address my immediate needs.